# Predicting % of demand going to each product

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression

I work within an industry with products that expire, therefore we would like to be able to choose which specific marketing keywords we should switch on to drive demand to the products that are over-stocked (and likely to expire at the current setup).

Therefore we would like to be able to say, If we turned on Keyword X, we predict that Product A would get a% of the purchases, Product B would get b% of the purchases and so on as these vague keywords can span multiple products.

I've been reading online that a Multinomial Logistic Regression model may be the best choice to predict probabilities to each product for each marketing keyword or campaign however given we have hundreds of different products and thousands of different keywords I was wondering whether this is feasible?

I am new to these models and therefore would like a more informed opinion on whether this is the best route please.

Comment: Your idea is incorrectly conceived. Logistics regression invokes 0 or 1. The output of probabilities is used to classify a set of related dimensions that results in particular domain ....

Comment: Could i not use logistic regression to extract the probabilities of purchasing each category/product? Then just use this to predict what proportion of customers will buy which product?

Comment: "choose which specific marketing keywords we should switch on to drive demand to the products that are over-stocked" And now you propose a new and different question ! I suppose you looking for one of marketing campaigns.